# How can I superimpose 2D arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

My task is to make a path from the leftmost column to the rightmost column of a 2D array which contains blocked numbers. The path must be composed of "pieces" that touch only in one block, and don't overlap. The pieces are normal tetris pieces: 3 blocks horizontal, 3 blocks vertical, corner, and reflected corner. They can't be rotated.

The 2d array is created via user input, and I format the array to contain a sequence of 0s and 1s, where 0 indicates "open" areas, and 1 indicates areas that the pieces can't go through, "blocked" areas.

My question is: how can I superimpose the "piece" arrays with the original large array to create the path? I googled "2d array superposition java" and didn't come up with much, so maybe it isn't possible. If it isn't, are there any other options for this problem?

For example: array is :

0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 0

We place the corner piece at (0,0). Now these cells are blocked and we have array:

**1 1** 0 0 1
1 **1** 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 0

Now the vertical piece:

1 1 0 0 1
1 1 **1** 0 1
0 1 **1** 1 0
1 1 **1** 0 0

Now reflected corner:

1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 **1**
1 1 1 **1 1**

And we output the sequence: "corner/vertical/reflected corner".

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Do you have any code snippet you could show ?

Comment: @LucienDubois I'm not even sure how to approach the superposition problem...

Comment: Show a picture or other example of what you are trying to do. It's extremely unclear what the problem actually is. A set of inputs with desired output would go a long way towards clarifying.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a simple method to check if the block overlaps with filled spaces on the board. In pseudocode, where x and y are the insertion coordinates:

```
field[][]
block[][]

isBlockBlocked(x,y){
    for each (a,b) in block {
        if( field[x+a][y+b] == 1 && block[a][b] == 1 ){
            return False;
        }
    }
    return True;
}
```

Best of luck with your assignment.

Comment: But how do you change the original array? Do you just hardcode it?

Comment: And also, why does it check if both the field is blocked and the piece is blocked?

Comment: You'll be able to pass the original and new array as parameters.

And... I assumed a `1` in both the field array and piece array indicated the presence of a block. Is this correct?